# How to fix springboot error Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException error during JRMP connection establishment

Tags: docker, maven, spring-data-cassandra, spring-boot-starter, jrmp

I am having issue with `springboot` `maven` project and `cassandra` in `docker`.
I want to execute `mvn verify` and in `pre-integration-test` to start cassandra docker and api server, execute test and then in `post-integration-test` to stop server but I am facing error `Could not contact Spring Boot application: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment;`

I have created `github` repo so you can easily reproduce error.

**Steps to reproduce**:

```
git clone https://github.com/gandra/docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed.git
cd docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed
mvn verify
```

this will produce error like this:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:start (api-server-start) @ docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.501 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-21T18:39:05+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:start (api-server-start) on project docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed: Could not contact Spring Boot application: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
[ERROR]     java.io.EOFException]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Any idea how to fix.

p.s.
I am working on mac and this solution would work on mac and linux as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code https://github.com/gandra/docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed is fixed and now working.

Basically 2 thing are changed:

1. Removed port mapping 9001 from docker-cassandra.sh.
2. Added `sleep 20` seconds in cassandra_start function in `docker-cassandra.sh` in order to give time cassandra to properly boot up. Not nice but at least working.

Now followiung code should work with 1 integration test executing successfully:

```
git clone https://github.com/gandra/docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed.git
cd docker-cassandra-with-initial-seed
mvn verify
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, there was an issue solved in 2020 that is a little bit tricky to find ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19048) the complete thread on Github if you want to read the full story).
Just to recap, the solution is to fix the `jmxPort`. For example:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <jmxPort>9011</jmxPort>
        </configuration>
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that he tries to use a port that is already in use.
I had a similar problem with spring boot (not with cassandra).

Two ways i see to solving this:

**First way:**

1. Find the program that is using that port (in my case it was "Intel(R) Graphics Command Center" on port 9001). (you can use netstat /a /b in command prompt) or use tcpview (external free program)
2. disable the program
3. Profit

**Second way**

configuring the jmx port in your pom on the spring-boot-maven-plugin
(Answer from sixro)
BUT, i don't like this way because you basically force the others in your project to use your workaround, while the issue is on your machien.